# How to automatically increase height of JFrame when I am adding components one by one dynamically

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am designing a swing standalone application. In my application I have a form  in which I am adding some components one by one dynamically when click on add button. My requirement is when I am adding components top to bottom, them jframe and Main jpanel must increase its height when the added component height exceeds.

Comment: `frame.pack()`,  or probably better, a `JList` with a suitable renderer in a `JScrollPane`.

Comment: Sir, when I am using JScollpane. but  when no of added  components exceeds the height of main jpanel . the main jpanel doesnot inceses its height automatically. plz suggest a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a ContainerListener to your JFrame. In the componentAdded method, pack the JFrame. Something like this:

```
    JFrame frame = getJFrame();
    frame.addContainerListener(new ContainerListener() {

        @Override
        public void componentAdded(ContainerEvent e) {
            frame.pack();
        }

        @Override
        public void componentRemoved(ContainerEvent e) {
        }
    });
```